# C# x SQL | Notification if Record does not exist

Tags: c#, sql

Beginner here! :) How can I receive a message that says that the Record ID I entered from C# does not exist in the database? Ive been searching for syntax of it but I find nothing. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, please make your question easier to understand by providing at least a few lines of code, or the error line, so that we can help you.

Comment: It really depends on why you need to know that. If you need the rest of the data, you could load it into a List<> or Dictionary<> or ?? and then search for ID by Contains(). If you just need to know whether or not the data exists, you could ExecuteScalar("select count(ID) where ID = X") and check for zero or ExecuteScalar("select ID where ID = X") and check for null. Take a look at https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=c-sharp%20check%20to%20see%20if%20db%20record%20exists and ask a specific question once you've played with things, or share what code you come up with and specific ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int i = ExecuteScalar("select count(RecordID) where RecordID = YourRecordID")
and Check it for Zero. 
Please paste some code snippet about the work you have done so far.